# Laptop turns off after 1 min when unplugged

Tags: windows-10

I have an Asus X541U laptop, which has a strange power saving (I believe) behaviour. When it is plugged into power and unplugged, it shuts down within about 1-2 minutes. Ie. the screen goes blank and everything turns off.

Then, when I power it on on battery, it again shuts off after about 15-20 minutes when working on it.

The laptop is about 9 months old and the battery shows near full during both incidences.

Here are the power settings as screenshots

[image]

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like 7.5 year old battery should be replaced

Comment: try to run your laptop in safemode and see if there is same behavior

Comment: @Ramhound haha, sorry this was a typo. its quite new

Comment: @user902300 The problem does not appear to happen in safe mode. How do I go about identifying what setting or program causes the issue?

Comment: first I would try to disable everything what is set to be started at windows start, then I would run full test with antivirus (preferably before windows booting), after that malware scan. then check for suspicious or latest installations. also there is possibility to go back in time with "system restore point" - if non helps then backup and fresh windows reinstall

Comment: How do you know the laptop is “shutting down?” What exactly do you experience? I ask because there are big clues in if the laptop is shutting down normally, going in to standby or hibernating, or powering off improperly. Do you know the difference? And which one is it? The system event log records why the laptop changes power states.

Comment: @Appleoddity Its not standby or hibernating, as it happens within 1 second. The screen goes black and the fan stops running. I don't think this issue is happening all the time. Would I find this is the System event log

Comment: Then what you describe sounds like it is physically powering off improperly. That event can be corroborated in the event log. If it is physically turning off improperly then it is not a software issue. It is a hardware issue. Most likely you have a bad battery. If the laptop is less than one year old then you should work with the manufacturer to get it serviced.